# How to add headers to HttpRequestMessageProperty in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, universal, ebay-api

I'm migrating some code to Universal Windows project from native C# project and trying to perform the following:

```
HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME", "APPID");
httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "findItemsByKeywords");
httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID", "EBAY-US");

OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
```

while in the C# native i am able to add headers to the collection, in UWP it's impossible.
seems like the HttpRequestMessageProperty.Headers in the System.ServiceModel.Http Version 4.0.1.0 is a Getter only...

what is the alternative in UWP ? 
How can i add headers to the collection ?

Answer (score 1):

well... googling:

```
httpRequestProperty.Headers["X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME"] = "APPID";
httpRequestProperty.Headers["X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME"] = "findItemsByKeywords";
httpRequestProperty.Headers["X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID"] = "EBAY-US";
```